# Same width/height columns in a table regardless of content, dynamically resized

Tags: css, css-tables

Is it possible for all rows and columns to have the same height, regardless wherever they contain an image or not?

Here's an [example](http://tinkerbin.com/QczmwBuD), it should be displayed as

```
[]    []  

  []
```

Comment: What do you mean "dynamically resized"? If different sized pictures were placed, for the table to resize appropriately?

Comment: Nope, the pictures are all the same size. It should change if you resize the window.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I can't get a perfect-looking JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Qdzrs/7/ but it did work for me when I tried it as a standalone file in my local computer.</strike>

I found a JQuery Plugin that works in the JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Qdzrs/8/ and it's called waitForImages.

1. the white spaces below the image seen in JSFiddle disappear in the standalone file.
2. You might get huge blocks of white space but that's because the image's aspect ratio doesn't match the cell's aspect ratio. I don't know if you want image stretched so I haven't looked into that.

Comment: It doesn't increase the size of the images if I resize the window :-(